# Determine if a group within a regex match is a number

Tags: python, regex

If I have, for example, the below regex string:

```
'^/abc/(?P<some_int>\d{3})/\d{0,2}/$'
```

Is there an easy way to determine when a group is a number/int?

---

I know that it is an int, but say this needed to be processed somewhere else and it needed to be deduced from just the match object.

Comment: Why would you need to *determine* it if you already *matched* it? I'm confused :)

Comment: if you could clarify what you are trying to ensure does not come through, that might help your question to get an answer

Comment: I have a method that handles various different matches that in turn calls function(s) using the group values as func params. Since the handling method does this for various regex's I wanted to be able to pass the groups that are numeric to the corresponding handling methods as such, just to avoid converting these all over the place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
m.group(WHICHEVER_YOU_WANT).isdigit()
```

Comment: Strings also already have the [`isdigit()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) method that more-or-less does exactly this.

Comment: Nice thinking outside the box :) I was so focused in on trying to use the information provided by the regex objects that I completely forgot about `isdigit`.. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are matching it with `\d{3}` so it will match only if it is a number with three digits ( including leading zeroes)

Comment: Yes, I do know that it is in fact a digit, since it passed the exp. What I was looking for was if a bit of unrelated code received the match could it determine which groups were matched as digits, using just the regex match/group objects.